# Best practice for common functions used by several Python projects

Tags: python

now I have a folder named my_funcs which have `__init__.py` and some .py files containing some functions and classes I wrote that I want to use for several projects.

So I want to know the best practice for these projects to direct import from this folder.

one solution is to `sys.path.append('.../my_funcs')`, in this case I will have to put this in front of the import statement for every .py file.

Any suggestions? BTW, I'm on Windows

Comment: Relevant to below answer. http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is to use PYTHONPATH.  Set it to the path where your common modules are found, before running Python.  Then you can just do `import my_funcs` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [PEP370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/), "Per user site-packages directory".

You set PYTHONUSERBASE to somewhere under your control, and you can see

```
$ PYTHONUSERBASE=/home/me/.local
$ python -m site --user-site
/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Your personal directory now appears in `sys.path`. `easy_install` respects this (using the `--user` option) so you can install "real" packages there, also, but make them available only to you.

Depending on your configuration, sounds like you could move your `my_funcs` directory under the site-packages directory and you're done!